# Hide Field within Permission Set

Tags: permission-sets

We recently set up PSA for use in our consulting business.  PSA developed a permission set for us to hide project actual costs within one of those permission sets.  However, you can still see revenue or project billings and margin.  Can anyone tell me in non-developer terms how to hide the project actuals margin field within the PSA?  I've tried doing this from Setup:Manager Users:Permission Sets, selecting that Permission Set and then selecting Object Settings and unchecking the read only box on margin, but that doesn't seem to work; users can still see the margin field.

Comment: Permission Sets are used to extend profile's permissions not restrict them, change the profiles to hide the fields then use a permission set to give access to the fields.

Answer (score 6):

Permission sets are not used to prevent access to fields, to do that go to the profiles for the relevant users and untick access on there.

Then use the Permission Sets to give access to the other fields to the users that need to see them.

[Permission Sets - Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_overview.htm&type=0)